# `gpg --edit-key <user>` not listing public key

Tags: encryption, passwords, gnupg, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to understand better how GnuPG works. When I run:

```
gpg --edit-key chloe
```

I would expect to see something like this (from the GnuPG privacy handbook):

```
Secret key is available.

pub  1024D/26B6AAE1  created: 1999-06-15 expires: never      trust: -/u
sub  2048g/0CF8CB7A  created: 1999-06-15 expires: never
sub  1792G/08224617  created: 1999-06-15 expires: 2002-06-14
sub   960D/B1F423E7  created: 1999-06-15 expires: 2002-06-14
(1)  Chloe (Jester) <chloe@cyb.org>
(2)  Chloe (Plebian) <chloe@tel.net>
```

with the public key listed alongside any subkeys.

Instead what I see is:

```
Secret key is available.

sec  2048g/0CF8CB7A created: 1999-06-15 expires: never usage: SC trust: ultimate validity: ultimate
ssb  960D/B1F423E7 created: 1999-06-15 expires: never usage: E
[ultimate] (1). Chloe (Jester) <chloe@cyb.org>
```

**Why is there a difference between my output and the example output?**

**Could somebody give an explanation of what my output means?**

Answer (score 3):

The example in the documentation seems outdated. GnuPG 1.4 lists the output you expected, and actually changes the display when running `toggle`. GnuPG 2.1 (maybe also 2.0, but I expect this to be specific to GnuPG 2.1 which merged private and public keyrings). immediately lists the private keys as such. While it still accepts the `toggle` command, it does not seem to perform any action (although I did not look up the implementation in the code). Also, it is not listed in the output of the `help` command.

The reason behind `toggle` in older versions of GnuPG is that it used two separate keyrings for public and private keys. `toggle` switched among which of the keyrings is edited. GnuPG 2.1 merged the private keys, thus the `toggle` command is not required any more.

Comment: [Opening a bug report](https://bugs.gnupg.org/) seems to be reasonable. I put this on my todo list and will open one after verifying the issue further and looking up whether there already is a matching issue, but will not get around to do so within the next days. If you open one, please drop a link to the report here (and consider referencing this Q&A in the bug report).

Comment: Since the output lists "sec" instead of the expected "pub", but the "fingerprint/key id" is the same, is it correct to infer that the fingerprint is shared by both public and private keys?